# How to get radio id in zend form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Hii...

I want the radio button id to be set as defined, but I am getting the id set with label value, please suggest where I am going wrong. Thanx... Here is what I have coded and the output of it...

```
 $suggestionMode = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('radioSuggestionMode');
 $suggestionMode->setLabel('')
            ->addMultiOptions(array('radioSuggestionMode'=>'Suggestion Mode'))
            ->setAttrib('checked','checked')
            ->setOptions(array('onclick'=>'selectSuggestionMode()'));
```

HTML OUTPUT I GET THE FOLLOWING WAY

```
<input id="radiSuggetionMode-radioSuggestionMode" type="radio" checked="checked" name="radioSuggestionMode">
```

BUT I WANT THE FOLLOWING WAY

```
<input id="radiSuggetionMode" type="radio" checked="checked" name="radioSuggestionMode">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get what you want is to extend the Zend_View_Helper_FormRadio like Marcin says. Look for it in Zend/View/Helper/FormRadio obviously

You can copy and paste the whole file for the most part, but there is one line of code that you have to change. ( besides the class name and all that )

```
            // generate ID
            $optId = $id . '-' . $filter->filter($opt_value);
```

Look for the above line and change it to :

```
            // generate ID
            $optId = $filter->filter($opt_value);
```

That will change the id to be the option value that you specified with the addMultiOption method.

I don't know if this will break any zend components that might expect the ID to be in the  id-value format but you can try.

After you create your class and edit it, you'll have to add the helper path to the view so it'll find it instead of the standard helper.

Let me know if that helps you out.

Comment: Thanx guys, I have updated the view helper to $optId = $id, now I get what I wanted... :)

Comment: This might give you trouble if you start adding more options since they'll all use the same id in this case but if it gives you what you want right now then great.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change it as such format of radio ID is hard coded into [Zend_View_Helper_FormRadio](https://github.com/mridgway/Zend-Framework-1.x-Mirror/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/FormRadio.php#L157). You would have to write your own custom view helper, based on the original [Zend_View_Helper_FormRadio](https://github.com/mridgway/Zend-Framework-1.x-Mirror/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/FormRadio.php#L157) that customizes ID generation.

Comment: if that is the case then name should also be shown as name="' . $name . '"'
id="' . $optId . '"'   , from the code, but it is not...

Comment: @Lakshman. so you want to have different name rather then id for your radio?

Comment: yes I want radio id as "radiSuggetionMode" instead of 
"radiSuggetionMode-radiSuggetionMode".

Comment: @Lakshman. You need to modify Zend_View_Helper_FormRadio or write your own, as there is no option or parameter in ZF to alter generation of id. Id is always in the following form: `$optId = $id . '-' . $filter->filter($opt_value)`;